# Display image from database showing same images

Tags: php, database, image, png, blob

I am trying to display an image coming from the database and I was able to get it but the problem is, it's displaying same images even though I uploaded different images.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("dbname");

$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table align='center'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<img src='getImage.php?id='".$row['id']."' height='230px' width='300px'> <br /><br />";   

//Some codes here...

echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**getImage.php**

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("dbname");

$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: image/png");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row['image'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Pls. help me...

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try clearing the browser cache... that will confirm it's not a client issue. (left shift+refresh generally does uncached reload in most modern browsers)

Comment: – John Conde thanks for that!

Comment: – Orangepill i tried clearing the browser cache but still the same. Seems like it's just showing the last id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm lazy, I'm going to assume id is numeric here.

In `getImage.php`:

We need to tell getImage.php to just get the image that has the ID we want.

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']); 
//Forces $id to be numeric.  You wouldn't have to worry about doing this if
//you used prepared statements.  Like those in John Conde's links.
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE `id`=$id";
```

As it is now, getImage.php is actually outputting all your images.  You only see the one with the latest date however.  This is because it's the first retrieved by your script thanks to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Also, in your display loop, change this:

```
echo "<img src='getImage.php?id='".$row['id']."' height='230px' width='300px'> <br /><br />";
```

to this:

```
echo "<img src='getImage.php?id=".$row['id']."' height='230px' width='300px'> <br /><br />";
```

Removed the extra single quote between id= and it's number, this way the number will actually be sent to your script.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the *getImage.php* does not return the corresponding image with *id* in query string. Your source codes always return the image of latest news, right?

Try to replace this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = {$_GET['id']} LIMIT 1";
```